# how to output the date from jquery ui datepicker and add a day each time its outputted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have an a jquery ui datepicker and i need to pick the date from this and then output it in a div and then for each div i need to add one day to it.

the html

```
<?php $date = $_POST['datepicker']; ?>

<input name="datepicker" class="calendarInput" type="text" id="datepicker">

<div>
<?php echo($date) ?>
</div>

<div>
<?php echo($date) ?>
</div>

<div>
<?php echo($date) ?>
</div>
```

thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the onSelect callback.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
   }
});
```

Assign ids to your divs and then you can modify the contents.

Comment: hi thanks for this how would i output this into my div and how could i get this to keep adding a date each time its outputted.